# Crushing pressure (15,750 psi) at the bottom of Marinas Trench

Tags: oceanography

If a human would be crushed if he were to scuba dive to the bottom of Marinas Trench then how do fish survive down there without being crushed?

Comment: The simple answer is that we're used to the pressure we grow up in.   The pressure inside the fish is the same as the pressure of the water, so it's in balance.  It's the same reason we don't "feel" air pressure even though there's a ton of air pressure against every square foot of skin.  An average human is about 16-21 square feet of surface area, so there's like 30,000 lbs of pressure on an average person all the time.   We don't feel it, cause it's equal pressure inside pushing out as outside pushing in.  That's why we feel like we're about to explode in a vacuum chamber.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it about fish physiology not physics

Comment: @John, You are right but I did wonder if there might be an interesting equivalent physics question about the properties of gases at high pressure and how that effects diffusion across membranes and how it affects chemical processes involving haemoglobin?

Comment: There are physical aspects to the question.   It's not entirely without physics, though perhaps better for biology SE.

Comment: Here's a fun article on this subject (note the title the "Physics" of deep sea animals.    http://discovermagazine.com/2001/aug/featphysics   The photo of the Styrofoam cup under ultra high pressure is worth a click all by itself.

Answer (score 1):

From a physics perspective the main factor here is  "pressure differential". As long as the pressure inside the fish and outside is the same, there no pressure differential and therefor no net force on the shell of the fish and there is no crushing. So the key here is proper pressure equalization as the depth changes.